# Mac get info always showing png icon instead of the icon

Tags: mac, icons, png

When I open 'Get Info' copy my icon over the default and it applies it but it never shows it. It only shows the default PNG icon (with the pictures and the camera).

Does anybody faced the problem before?
I can't figure out any solution to change the file icon.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 18):

You have to paste the contents of the image instead of the file. For example open the image in Preview, press ⌘A and ⌘C, open an information window for the target file in Finder, click the image well in the top left corner, and press ⌘V.

Answer (score 0):

You must be copying a PNG file.

Note that Mac OS X uses icns files as icons. So, first convert your PNG to ICNS and then repeat the steps you did before.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how to accomplish that?

Comment: You can use a free Mac Application called Image2icon to accomplish the above. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/image2icon-make-your-own-icons/id992115977?mt=12

Comment: There are many free websites as well which can convert png to icns and vice versa

Comment: It is NOT necessary to convert the png file first. See the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to:

- create a new folder,
- paste the copied image onto its preview icon in the Info dialog,
- drag the contents of the old folder into the new folder,
- delete the old folder, and
- change the name of the new folder to that of the old folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that worked for me at
https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/fix-macos-file-icon-previews-not-showing/

Follow that link for the detailed instructions, but in short:

1. From the Activity Monitor, search for com.apple.quicklook.ThumbnailsAgent and force quit it.
2. Go to Apple menu select "Force Quit...", select Finder and click "Relaunch"

After that Finder relaunched and re-opened all the finder windows I'd had open, and now the png files were no longer generic icons but the contents of the files themselves.